# Hierarchical dictionary where the values of the embedded dictionary are lists. How to get the mean of each list?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {200101: {1: [350, 400, 150], 2: [350, 200, 240]}, 200102: {1: [200, 250, 100], 2: [300, 450, 400]}, 200103: {1: [200, 365, 199], 2: [200,200,200]}}
```

How would I iterate over the hierarchical dictionary to get the mean for each value in the embedded dictionaries (which are lists)?

This is the result I would like:

```
{200101: {1: 300, 2: 263.33}, 200102: {1: 183.33, 2: 383.33}, 200103: {1: 254.66, 2: 200}}
```

I have tried the following code:

```
import statistics
outer_dict = {}
inner_dict = {}
for st,vals in my_dict.items():
    outer_dict.update({st: inner_dict})
    for st1, vals1 in vals.items():
        inner_dict.update({st1: statistics.mean(vals1)})
```

And when I call

```
outer_dict
```

It returns

```
{200101: {1: 254.66666666666666, 2: 200}, 200102: {1: 254.66666666666666, 2: 200}, 200103: {1: 254.66666666666666, 2: 200}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)!

Example:

```
from statistics import mean

new_dict = {i: {k: mean(i) for k, i in j.items()} for i, j in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Sweeet use of dict comprehension, just 1 suggestion, the OP is using `statistics.mean` to calculate mean, which might be different than plain old mean (in terms of precision etc.. )

Comment: @Srini What's "plain old mean"?

Comment: You're right, I was using another stat lang for a while and got confused, `mean` is not built in. But `mean` is invoked as `statistics.mean` in the OP's code. And yes, you can also import mean from statistics as you have done as well

Comment: I just forgot the import Statement XD

Answer (score 0):

You replace all inner dicts by the same single `inner_dict` object, that's why it's that wrong.

Working version:

```
for d in my_dict.values():
    for k in d:
        d[k] = statistics.mean(d[k])
```